# Graph API & Upload file to Sharepoint Document library

Tags: sharepoint, graph, upload, drive

I try to upload files to sharepoint document library using the Graph API.
The request is : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveid}}/root:/myfolder/mydoc.pdf:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7B%7Bdriveid%7D%7D/root:/myfolder/mydoc.pdf:/content)
The request goes with bearer token and the binary file in the body.
The response is "201 Created" and all seems to be good.
But in the document library I can see the folder but there is no file at all.
(If I look at files in the sharepoint with GET request I can see the file !).
Can you help me to find why files are not visible in the sharepoint web view ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to my problem.
For the file to be visible by all users, you have to checkin the uploaded file with a POST request from the Graph API.